# Set width of Spinner to width of dropdown list

Tags: android, spinner

In my app, I have a spinner which loads values entered by the user. But the spinner always is much wider than the text it contains. How do I set the width of my spinner to exactly fit the size of the contents in the drop down? I don't want the extra space it is occupying because it is hindering other UI components.

I have given `wrap content`. I also tried with `setDropDownWidth`, it did not help.

This is the code of my `spinner`.

```
    sub[i].setAdapter(adapter);
    sub[i].setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    sub[i].setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);                          
    sub[i].setSelection(subArray.indexOf(timetableArray.get(i)));
```

Comment: provide xml of components.

Comment: I'm not doing using xml. I'm dynamically creating the spinner. Its has 2 radio buttons next to it.

Comment: Provide the code you've written then, if not using XML. There's nothing for us to go off of to help you with your issue.

Comment: @ChantellOsejo I've added the code.

Comment: What LayoutParams are you using?

Comment: if I use `LayoutParams` the view wasn't getting generated. So i dint use any.